# QGIS 3: Need to bind "zoom last" and "zoom next", is there a standard/customary setting for them? I'm considering Shift+leftArrow and Shift+rightArrow

Tags: qgis-3, zoom, shortcuts

I find it indispensable to have a keyboard shortcut for the "zoom last" and "zoom next" commands.

I'm considering binding them to **shift+leftArrow** and **shift+rightArrow** which as of now, wthout binding them, will do exactly the same as just pressing the arrows; that is, they'll just pan left or right. (It'd also be consistent with *Shift+mouseClick&drag* for zooming.)

But since I'm not completely sure these combinations aren't already supposed to work some way or another, I thought I'd ask for your opinion because I've also heard stories about QGIS sometimes getting touchy about customized keyboard shortcuts. Couldn't tell wether they're real, though.

Do you think it would be ok/safe to do so? If not advisable, could you please explain why? Or, if you know about other standard customs, please do tell, and who is/are using those shortcuts.

Comment: You can check (and modify) your current bindings with `Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts...`

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @Matt. I'm actually aware of it. And I've even been using these bindings for a few hours now. They do work, but I'd like to confirm that these bindings aren't gonna break anything. Or if there's a best practice already established.